# Show that $0 \in \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le 1}\} \implies 0 \in \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le \epsilon}\}, \forall \epsilon>0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

In the proof of Proposition. 1.3. page 100 Functional Analysis book of Conway the following claim ($X$ is a TVS and $p$ is a seminorm.)

If $0 \in \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le 1}\}$ then $0 \in \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le \epsilon}\}$ for every $\epsilon >0$. How this is true?

Comment: Suppose $0 \in  \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le 1}\}$. 
Given $\varepsilon >0$, let $f: X \rightarrow X$ be defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} x$. We have that $f$ is continuous.  Now, $\operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le 1}\}$ is an open set in $X$ and so we have that $f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le 1}\})$ is an open set in $X$ and 
$$ 0 \in  f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int}\{x \in X : p(x) \le 1\}) \subseteq \{x \in X : p(x) \le \varepsilon\}$$
So, $0\in  \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le \varepsilon}\}$.

Comment: @Ramiro, though the other solution is correct but your correct solution is 1- different and 2- has simpler backgrounds. I will accept it if you would like to post it.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. If $$0 \not\in \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le \epsilon}\},$$ there exists a net $\{x_j\}$ such that $p(x_j)>\epsilon$ and $x_j\to0$. As multiplication by a scalar is continuous, $\frac1\epsilon x_j\to0$;  and $p(\frac1\epsilon x_j)>1$, so $$0 \not \in \operatorname{Int}{\{x \in X : p(x) \le 1}\}.$$